# Literature in ModernCV

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

I currently write my CV and I want to include a Bibliography. The following is my header:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{multibib,chapterbib, babelbib}

\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}

\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
```

So now I want to include a Bibliography, but I have the following problems with it:

1. The bibliography itself is indented nearly half the page. How to force Latex to start at a "normal" left margin?
2. The numbers for the different sources are not shown in the bibliography, even though in the CV the numbers appear if I \cite{} them, and if you want to look the source up, you have to count through. What to do to make the numbers appear in the bibliography too? Maybe something is missing in my header.\

Thank you.

Comment: Those end of lines commands \\ will produce errors; remove them from the preamble. Please modify your example code: turn it into a complete and minimal document illustrating the problem.

Comment: As i side note, I just noticed that you haven't accepted or up-voted any of the answers to your questions. Please consider up-voting good answers and accepting the ones that best solved your problems (up-voting and accepting are two different actions); in case of doubt on how/why to accept answers,please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Will do as soon as I registered!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `moderncv` doesn't show labels in the bibliography; to show them, add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bibliographyitemlabel{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
```

The other issue requires a redefinition of the `thebibliography` environment (`filecontents*` is not essential in the solution; it's just to get a complete example):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{xxyyy.bib}
@book{testa,
    author = "The AuthorA",
    title = "The TitleA",
    year = "2012",
    publisher = "The PublisherA"
}
@book{testb,
    author = "The AuthorB",
    title = "The TitleB",
    year = "2012",
    publisher = "The PublisherB"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multibib,chapterbib, babelbib}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bibliographyitemlabel{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]%
  {%
     \setlength\hintscolumnwidth{0pt}
     \setlength\separatorcolumnwidth{0pt}
     \bibliographyhead{\refname}%
%    \small%
    \begin{list}{\bibliographyitemlabel}%
      {%
        \setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
        \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
        \settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \@openbib@code%
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty%
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
  }%
  {%
    \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    \end{list}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xxyyy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the numbering works alright. But still it is indented and I want to put the bibliography a bit more to the left side. And if possible, I want a title "Bibliography" in bold and bigger letters. How to do this?

Comment: @maad I've updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: Works super perfect and is doing exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Gonzalo.

Comment: There is actually no need to redefine the `thebibliography` environment. All you need is to put `\setlength\hintscolumnwidth{0pt}` and `\setlength\separatorcolumnwidth{0pt}` before `\bibliography{xxyyy}`.

Comment: @Xavier I thought about it too, but then the labels and the references are too close; that's why I decided to redefine the environment.

Comment: @Gonzola If you don't want that, then simply don't do write `\setlength\separatorcolumnwidth{0pt}`. I just saw now that you redefine it again as `\setlength\separatorcolumnwidth{0.25\textwidth}` 5 lines after :)

Comment: @Xavier The first redefinition (setting it to `0pt`) affects the title "Literatur" (the deafult value would produce an indented title). Once the title is typeset (with no indentation) I restore the original value so entries will have some extra spacing from their labels.

Comment: @Gonzalo My bad, I hadn't seen you also redefined the bibliography header.